# Keep NERDTree on right side when closing buffer

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I have NERDTree configured to open on the right side with

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
```

This works when I open a new buffer. However, when I close a buffer on the left side with `:bd`, NERDTree takes the whole window and loses it's split. It looks like this.

[image: NERDTree open on the right, another buffer open on the left]
[image: Buffer closed on the left with <code>:bd</code>, NERDTree displays at the left side, using all space]

Is there a way to keep NERDTree at the right side?

And secondly, can I force that new buffers are always opened at the left side with Ctrl-P? Sometimes it pretty annoying when the focus is inside NERDTree on the left side, I press Ctrl-P, and the file is displayed within the small buffer in which NERDTree was displayed.

Comment: honestly, maybe there is a solution for this. But i recommend reading this: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/ and then considering to switch to https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar

Comment: I agree, I switched to netrw + vinegar after becoming frustrated by this kind of thing, it's a much nicer workflow

Answer (score 0):

As a Nerdtree user myself, I'd say, that this is normal behaviour. If you close the last open buffer, the remaining buffer (in this case Nerdtree) will take the full screen.

I imagine, this is annoying and the remedy is usually something like this:

`map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` to toggle Nerdtree only when needed.

The other "trick" is to close it automatically, when opening a file via

`let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1`.